# How can I align layers side-by-side and crop them automatically in Photoshop CS5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5, crop

How can I align layers side-by-side and crop them automatically in Photoshop CS5?

Example:
[image: example]

Comment: Can you describe in greater detail what you mean by "crop them automatically"?  What is the end result you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the same technique I detailed **[here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/18870/8708)**.

Essentially, surround each layer with a guide, then use the slice tool (specifically the ***Slices From Guides*** button from the toolbar), then you can use **File** → ***Save For Web & Devices...*** to "automatically" crop each layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing your own or looking for existing scripts for Photoshop (.jsx file) to crop images

I would try to find a script that cuts an image then saves just the cut one...
you can use save for we to do that.