# How to slice images as PNG for iOS app in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, slices, ios

I have a finished design for my iOS app, but the developers don't use PS and asked me to provide all the UI elements as PNGs for retina and standard. The designer who originally created the design in PS stated that he doesn't do slicing.

1. Is there a way to do this automatically? If not which is the best method to do it?
2. Isn't it usual that the designer provides this per request?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

There is a semi-automatic way to slice images, that is using the **Slice Tool**.

You can use it to subdivide your file into blocks of icons:

[image: Sliced PSD]

When you use **File** → ***Save For Web & Devices...*** Photoshop will export each slice as a separate image for you:

[image: Sliced Images]

This is a non-destructive method, so you can still make changes to the icons if needed and still use the same slices. There are a couple ways you could resize all the icons for retina/standard: either resize the whole image prior to saving or you could batch resize them all after they are already saved.

Whether or not your designer will slice up your images for you depends on the agreement you have in place with your designer. If it wasn't part of the contract, they aren't obligated to do so. I'm sure they'll be happy to do it for a fee :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how can I make sure that I have marked/sliced it accurately? I mean do you zoom in, also do you include the shadows? Just generally how can I make sure that I make it right without loosing quality or damaging it in any way? Thx

Comment: My method for this instance was to surround each icon with guides. So yes, I zoomed in close enough to see the pixels, then held shift while dragging the guides so that they would snap between the pixels. Once all the guides were set, I clicked the ***Slices From Guides*** button on the Slice toolbar.

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean by "Do you include the shadows?" since I don't know what your images looks like, but yes I would presume you should include the shadows.

Answer (score 1):

Usually designer will provide all slice images.
I am not sure we can make slicing automatically.
an
Retina you can give images as per psd.
non-retina you need to give half of the retina size.
while saving images for non-retina -  scale Retina images to 50% and save as png.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do this automatically? If not which is the best
>   method to do it?

You can absolutely do this automatically in **Photoshop**. You would use a [Batch Action](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18721/how-to-apply-a-layer-to-multiple-open-images-in-photoshop/18723#18723).

> You'll need to perform the action once to record what you want to do,
>   then setup a **Batch Action** under **File > Automate > Batch**.

Just to expand on what **MK_** said, *Retina* display images are shown as double the size, so if your image is supposed to be 56 x 56px, then your retina image should be 112 x 112px. So what you should do is create your Retina images first, then use the above batch action steps to reduce the sizes and create a set of images for the standard display.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Photoshop CC I'd strongly recommend you check out the [new support for exporting assets](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html) - it's *much* quicker and easier than slices and allows you to go back and make adjustments to your assets without having to edit the slices again. All you need to do is label your layers in a particular way and let the generator do the work for you.

Answer (score -2):

You can try using [codly.io](http://codly.io/?utm_source=Q%26A&utm_medium=Answers&utm_campaign=QA) you can convert your photoshop design into native code in seconds,just From Photoshop PSD to Code.

you can slice your PHOTOSHOP design  automatically.
 and generate assets for all application screens.and more

save 40% of of the whole application development timeframe.